# EF suddenly cannot be found

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

While working on my MVC 5 project, the main db reference seems to have been broken.

> CS0246 The type or namespace 'IntranetEntities' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

When I am in the Model.edmx, it will link to the SQL server and update.

What would cause my "IntranetEntities" db reference to be broken?

How can I re-establish it?

Comment: Do you have added refference to the project? Do you have using namespace in your code?

Comment: Your ADO.Entity datamodel must be in a separate project, if you refer that project in your main project you should be ok, i do not know why would your references disapear but it happened to me one time and i could not find why.

Comment: Try cleaning the bin/obj files and rebuilding

Comment: It looks like there might have been something going on with the network communications that day. The database is on the server. The next day everything was linked back to the database. Very odd since I had no connectivity issues with the server using SQL management studio. Thanks for the replies.